# Font renders thicker in browsers

Tags: css, browser, fonts, adobe-illustrator

I am using the Open Sans font on a web site, but it appears much thicker in all browsers than in Adobe Illustrator (see attached images). Why is this and is there any way I can get the font in the browser to display "thinner" please?

[image: Illustrator]

[image: Browser]

**Note**
Both the browser and Illustrator are rendering the Semibold weight (600)

Comment: WRT your edit: Is your question how to make the browser use a thinner font than weight 600?

Comment: Please post the HTML and CSS code you are using. It is normal to have fonts rendered differently by different programs, but the difference here looks too big to be explainable by that alone.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The issue was with aliasing. The following css solution will work for safari, chrome and firefox:

```
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Can anyone explain why this works and what we're losing by setting this?

Comment: @Matt "Smooth the font on the level of the pixel, as opposed to the subpixel. Switching from subpixel rendering to antialiasing for light text on dark backgrounds makes it look lighter" - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-smooth

Comment: Love this. So much cleaner. Should be the default behaviour in my opinion

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you're including the light (300) and normal (400) weights for Open Sans, then you can simply:

```css
body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300; /* Or 400, if 300 is too light. */
}
```

Comment: Thanks, please see update to question

Comment: @RunLoop are you using the same font size? Are you using `pt` units?

Comment: I am using px in both cases.

Comment: @RunLoop can you not simply change the font weight in the browser from Semibold to Normal?

Comment: Unfortunately not, the regular and semibold weights appear quite differently.

Comment: Don't you mean `font-weight` instead of `font-size`?

Comment: @FredericLeitenberger Well spotted.

Answer (score 0):

The Open Sans Webfont comes in 10 styles. For me it looks like the browser displays the semibold one. It should be regular and you should go fine.

Take a look at fontsquirrel

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/open-sans

Comment: I think you mean "10 weights". There are only 3 different font styles!

Comment: You're right - I meant styles because all weights have single stylesheets :)

Answer (score -1):

The simple answer is that there isn't a fix. If you are properly loading and calling the desired style and weight, then sometimes things just render differently between adobe and web browsers (or browser to browser). Your options are to go to 400 weight or learn to love the boldness.